# Can't Access Move.mil on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro

I am currently trying to connect to move.mil and safari won't let me use it because it is not receiving "valid" certificates from it, how do I bypass this because I used to use this site all the time on my windows computer but now I can't on my MacBook

Answer (score 2):

The certificate issue is not your fault and there’s nothing to bypass. They need to resolve the issue.

> DPS is experiencing intermittent outages that may prevent access or limit functions.  The program is aware of the issue and actively troubleshooting.  This notice will be removed once the issue is resolved.